# InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement (Google maps)

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-places-api

I am trying to make a simple autocomplete field for google map places, but I get the following error message **even though my field is HtmlInputElement**

> InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement

html:

```
<input type="text" id="input"/>
<div id="map" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var map_input = $('#input');
    setTimeout(function(){initMap()},'5000');
    function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map($('form #map'), {
            center: {lat: 33.8892846, lng: 35.539302},
            zoom: 11
        });

        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(map_input);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map
        });

        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            if (!place.geometry) {
                // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
                // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
                window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
                return;
            }

            // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
                //map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                //map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
            }

            marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
            marker.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
});
```

[check this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ademxhza/2/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your "input element" is **not** an instance of HTMLInputElement.  It is a JQuery array.  This will work:

```
var map_input = $('#input')[0];
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ademxhza/6/)

**code snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var map_input = $('#input')[0];
    setTimeout(function(){initMap()},'5000');
    function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map($('form #map'), {
            center: {lat: 33.8892846, lng: 35.539302},
            zoom: 11
        });
        
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(map_input);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map
        });

        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            if (!place.geometry) {
                // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
                // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
                window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
                return;
            }

            // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
                //map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                //map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
            }
            
            marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
            marker.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<input type="text" id="input"/>
<div id="map" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to access the DOM elements directly instead of the jQuery object - e.g. change `$('#map')` to `$('#map')[0]`.